# MLA Works Cited question

Tags: research-process, citations, citation-style

In a research paper, according to MLA standards, if I cite an author on page 259 in one paragraph (Author, 259), and 3 paragraphs later cite the same author from the same book but from a different page (Author, 628), how should the works cited entries look? Do I need two separate entries for each citation, or can I make one entry and put pages 259-628 in the works cited listing?

For example, if I write in a paper that "Saturn has many rings (de Pater and Lissauer, 457)" and in another part of the paper say that "the age of Saturn's rings is unknown (de Pater and Lissauer, 484)".

How would the works cited listing look with the page numbers? Would I put in 457-484 (457 through 484), or 457, 484 (457 and 484)?

Answer (score 1):

The reference list only indicates the page numbers of the whole article within the book or journal etc in which it is contained. The citation indicates the page(s) within the article to which you are referring.

See https://www.library.cornell.edu/research/citation/mla